MDX not rendering markdown or styles
Currently trying to make a guide/blog-type project, and I'm trying to use MDX for my longform text content. My project uses Vite and React, using Tailwind for the styles. I am not using Next.js (I know there's a similar post somewhere with a similar issue to mine but none of the solutions worked for me). Currently, when I try to use something like an ordered list using markdown syntax in an MDX file, it simply does not appear on the page at all. All it does is render the text to the screen without the ordered list.
Here are some relevant files, let me know if you need to see anything else:
package.json:
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/rollup": "^3.0.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.13",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import mdx from "@mdx-js/rollup";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    { enforce: "pre", ...mdx(/* jsxImportSource: ..., otherOptions... */) },
    react({ include: /\.(jsx|mdx|md|tsx|ts)$/ }),
  ],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },
});

I tried the first answer in this Stack Overflow issue, and that didn't do anything. I didn't follow the second solution as I don't use TypeScript.
